# GithubActions deploying WebGoat on ECS - Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile webgoat.jar

Tags: java, docker, github-actions, amazon-ecs, webgoat

I am using the referred files and Dockerfile of WebGoat here https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat to deploy on ECS. It has been working well until I changed to GithubActions deployment recently

The ECS task kept failing with the error `Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile webgoat.jar`

I checked to run locally by building the image (`docker build -f Dockerfile . -t webgoat/webgoat`) and run (`/mvnw spring-boot:run`) as shown here https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat#4-run-from-the-sources

However when I tried to deploy to ECS with Githubactions and Codebuild, it kept having the above error. All previous stages run fine, Codebuild test succeeded.

[image: github stages]

I didn't change anything about the Dockerfile. Can't find much clue elsewhere, anyone might have encountered this?

My Dockerfile

```
FROM docker.io/eclipse-temurin:19-jre-focal
LABEL NAME = "WebGoat: A deliberately insecure Web Application"
MAINTAINER "WebGoat team"

RUN \
  useradd -ms /bin/bash webgoat && \
  chgrp -R 0 /home/webgoat && \
  chmod -R g=u /home/webgoat

USER webgoat

COPY --chown=webgoat target/webgoat-*.jar /home/webgoat/webgoat.jar

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 9090

WORKDIR /home/webgoat
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", \
  "-Duser.home=/home/webgoat", \
  "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8", \
  "--add-opens", "java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED", \
  "--add-opens", "java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED", \
  "--add-opens", "java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED", \
  "--add-opens", "java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED", \
  "--add-opens", "java.desktop/java.beans=ALL-UNNAMED", \
  "--add-opens", "java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED", \
  "--add-opens", "java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED", \
  "--add-opens", "java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED", \
  "--add-opens", "java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED", \
  "-Drunning.in.docker=true", \
  "-Dwebgoat.host=0.0.0.0", \
  "-Dwebwolf.host=0.0.0.0", \
  "-Dwebgoat.port=8080", \
  "-Dwebwolf.port=9090", \
  "-jar", "webgoat.jar" ]
```

My githubactions workflow `yml` file (checked and ENV VAR is replaced correctly)

```
name: Deploy to Amazon ECS

on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]

env:
  AWS_REGION: xxx # set this to your preferred AWS region, e.g. us-west-1 aavsfd
  ECR_REPOSITORY: xxx # set this to your Amazon ECR repository name
  ECS_SERVICE: xxx# set this to your Amazon ECS service name
  ECS_CLUSTER: xxx # set this to your Amazon ECS cluster name
  ECS_TASK_DEFINITION:
    taskdef.json # set this to the path to your Amazon ECS task definition
    # file, e.g. .aws/task-definition.json
  CONTAINER_NAME:
    my-app # set this to the name of the container in the
    # containerDefinitions section of your task definition

permissions:
  contents: read
  statuses: read

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production

    steps:
      - name: Check commit status
        id: commit-status
        run: |
          # Check the status of the Git commit
          CURRENT_STATUS=$(curl --url https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/commits/${{ github.sha }}/status --header 'authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}' | jq -r '.state');
          echo "Current status is: $CURRENT_STATUS"
          while [ "${CURRENT_STATUS^^}" = "PENDING" ];
            do sleep 10;
            CURRENT_STATUS=$(curl --url https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/commits/${{ github.sha }}/status --header 'authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}' | jq -r '.state');
          done;
          echo "Current status is: $CURRENT_STATUS"
          if [ "${CURRENT_STATUS^^}" = "FAILURE" ];
            then echo "Commit status failed. Canceling execution";
            exit 1;
          fi

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

      - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
        id: build-image
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
          IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
        run: |
          # Build a docker container and
          # push it to ECR so that it can
          # be deployed to ECS.
          docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
          docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
          echo "image=$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
        id: task-def
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
        with:
          task-definition: ${{ env.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }}
          container-name: ${{ env.CONTAINER_NAME }}
          image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}

      - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
        with:
          task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
          service: ${{ env.ECS_SERVICE }}
          cluster: ${{ env.ECS_CLUSTER }}
          wait-for-service-stability: true
```